# C# : Logic Implementation improvement along with performance

Tags: c#, .net, performance, c#-4.0

I've been writing some logic to set property based on certain condition. I would like to improve following logic in better way :

```
string detail = GetDetail();
if (detail.StartsWith("stackoverflow:"))
{
    detailItem.Stackoverflow = detail.Replace("stackoverflow:", string.Empty).Trim();
    continue;
}
if (detail.StartsWith("google:"))
{
    detailItem.Google = detail.Replace("google:", string.Empty).Trim();
    continue;
}
if (detail.StartsWith("facebook:"))
{
    detailItem.Facebook = detail.Replace("facebook:", string.Empty).Trim();
    continue;
}
if (detail.StartsWith("twitter:"))
{
    detailItem.Twitter = detail.Replace("twitter:", string.Empty).Trim();
    continue;
}
```

Comment: Use Substring instead of Replace

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get the text before the colon and use it in a `switch`. Get the text after the colon too, so you don't have to repeat the code for that:

```
string detail = GetDetail();
int index = detail.IndexOf(':');
if (index != -1) {
  string before = detail.Substring(0, index);
  string after = detail.Substring(index + 1).Trim();
  switch (before) {
    case "stackoverflow": detailItem.Stackoverflow = after; break;
    case "google": detailItem.Google = after; break;
    case "facebook": detailItem.Facebook = after; break;
    case "twitter": detailItem.Twitter = after; break;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

another way is to use a method that takes your token as parameter and return the value, something like

```
public string GetValue(string token, string text, string defaultValue=null){
   return text.StartsWith(token) ? text.Replace(token, string.Empty).Trim() : defaultValue;
}
```

and you can call it this way

```
string detail = "google:blablabla";
string result = GetValue("google:",detail, null);
```

the 3rd parameter can be used to place whatever text you want if it is not what you expect, so you can pass there your actual value or null or another string

so if you want to preserve your actual values, you can call like

```
detailItem.Facebook = GetValue("facebook:",detail, detailItem.Facebook);
```

here the link to a fiddle to show you the result
https://dotnetfiddle.net/LWQY2e